# Photo Flash Animation like Photo Booth Mac Application in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, animation

I need to show the Photo Flash Animation present in the Photo Booth Mac application in iOS.

How to do that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "flash" in Photo Booth for Mac is just a white surface, isn't it. To replicate it, I would:

1. Create a transparent window that covers the entire screen (or multiple windows if there are multiple screens).
2. Place a `CALayer` inside the window. Then animate the change of the layer's background color from transparent to white and back.
3. Remove the window from the screen.